# How can I read a CSV file in android

Tags: java, android

The timetable.csv file is in the same directory as the MainActivity.java. I used the following function.

```
public void getaction(String date, TextView action1) {

    String line = "";

    String[] football = new String[20];
    try {
        System.out.print("Hello");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("timetable.csv"));
        String headerLine = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Hello");
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            football = line.split(",");
            //match the date
            if(football[0].equals(date)){
                action1.setText("i found chelsea");
            }else{
                action1.setText("I did not find Chelsea!");
            }
        }


    }
    catch(Exception io){
            System.out.println(io);

        }

    action1.setText("I did too find Chelsea!");
}
```

It gave the following error:

> I/System.out: Hellojava.io.FileNotFoundException: timetable.csv (No
>   such file or directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create **assets** Folder in app module. Paste your .csv file there.
Then you can read a file like this

```
try
{

reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.csv")));
......
}
catch (Exception e)
{

......
}
```